# Batch removing leading dash in file names in Bash

Tags: bash, batch-rename

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  6156 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140728.151116.pgp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  2756 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140728.152042.pgp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  3424 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140729.141735.pgp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  2439 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140729.142515.pgp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  2672 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140730.125115.pgp
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ywang  Users  2391 Aug 16 14:38 -STEST.20140730.125556.pgp
```

Hi, I've tried multiple ways, e.g. looping through the file and do `mv` one by one. However, I wasn't successful as the caveat was that `mv` interprets the leading dash as a parameter to itself and backslash escaping doesn't seem to work when combining with the wildcard `*`.

Any ideas how it can be done in a oneliner in Bash? Thanks!

Comment: Not bash, but it solves your problem: http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/.  `rename s/^-// -*` (untested).  Also, most commands take `--` to signal the end of options, so you can use them with files that start with `-`.  `mv -- -blah blah`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i in ./-*; do mv "$i" "${i#*-}"; done
```

It is important to use `./-*` for globbing so that shell doesn't interpret `-` as command option.